# gtksourceview / gedit syntax-highlighting : highlighting a 'shell' sub-section

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, gedit, gtksourceview

I'm writing a `.lang`  gtksourceview/gedit file for the **nextflow** language. In this language, there are some sections starting and ending with `"""` and containing some `shell` statements. ( My xml/lang file is here : https://github.com/lindenb/nextflow.lang/blob/master/nextflow.lang )

I'm trying to highlight the `shell` section using

```
<context ref="sh:sh"/>
```

but it doesn't work. The 'pink' part doesn't stop after `"""` (right bottom panel below).

How can I fix this ?

Thanks.

[image]